# IntelliJ LibGDX Runtime - NoSuchFieldError: gl

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, intellij-idea, libgdx

I have an error in IntelliJ. I am working on an simple game under libGDX and IntelliJ IDE. I generated project through libGDX Setup Generator:

[image: libGDX Project Setup]

I am using also some other libraries like Mockito and tween engine:

```
Joda Convert    1.7
BodyEditor-Loader   2.9
Mockito 1.9.5
Java Tween Engine   6.3.3
Square Otto 1.3.5
LibGDX  1.3.1 (??)
```

I am getting this error after running Desktop app:

```
*Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: gl
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: gl
    at com.enplug.apps.example.SampleScreen.render(SampleScreen.java:47)
    at com.enplug.sdk.hosting.HostedGame.render(HostedGame.java:61)
    at com.enplug.player.hosting.GameHost.render(GameHost.java:268)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:206)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)*
```

I have found on internet, that I should update my libraries, because it can contain version mismatch, but this one: http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/2012/09/libgdx-project-setup-v3-0-0/ seems to be old and it doeasn't recognize my projects created from libGDX Project setup:

[image: LibGDX Project Setup]

Can you help me? I just need to recognize, what libraries should make problem. Any advice will help!

Picture of my error as image:

[image: NoSuchFieldError: gl]

Comment: Can you post SampleScreen code? Error is thrown at `com.enplug.apps.example.SampleScreen.render(SampleScreen.java:47)`. What's there?

Comment: But it is defined in .jar library which was given from third part. But here is structure: http://pastebin.com/aSb3YPen

Comment: Can you check which depenciencies this library needs? Which versions?
The code would help to know which object should have the gl attribute. Maybe you can decompile the jar using [jad](http://varaneckas.com/jad/)

Comment: It seems to me that the enplug sdk your are using was compiled against an old version of libgdx.

Comment: Are you using openGL ES 1.0 ? If so, the support for 1.0 has been removed in libgdx now and you need to use openGL ES 2.0

Comment: It was problem caused by enplug sdk, which was compiled against older version of libgdx